# How to change css on link current class

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

How do I make my font color white, on the current nav bar class?

For example, when I click on a link on the nav it adds a class="current" to that link.

But I'm having trouble styling that particular link.

Here's the HTML:

```
<div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-loggedin-nav mineul pull-right" style="font-size:22px;margin-top:7px; color:white;">
<li>
<a class="current" href="/">
</li>
<li>
```

Here's my CSS attempt which is way off:

```
.nav > li > a .current {
    color: white;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.nav > li > a.current
```

Just a small change.  The space between "a" and ".current" makes it think .current is a new element.

Answer (score 0):

No space between the anchor element selector and the class name selector:

```
.nav > li > a.current {
    color: white;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

HTML

```
<div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-loggedin-nav mineul pull-right" style="font-size:22px;margin-top:7px; color:white;">
<li>
<a class="current" href="/">Text Here</a>
</li>
<li>
```

CSS

```
a.current {
    color: white;
}
```

Comment: How do you think the question is misusing it? The code in the question uses the `>` perfectly correctly.